# Read 1 byte from file

Tags: c

I need to read a single byte from a file. Normally when reading, I use a char array as the buffer. However, I need to be able to perform binary operations with byte, which can't be done with a char array. Here's what I've got:

```
read(file, buffer, 1);
```

I've tried making buffer both a char and an int, but both give me warnings that it expects a void * argument. But of course, that doesn't allow for binary operations like &.

How can I store buffer such that I can perform binary operations on it?

Comment: read expects an address, `char c; read(file, &c, 1);` should be enough.

Comment: or `unsigned char c; read(file, &c, 1)` to read byte.

Comment: 1) [ask], provide a [mcve] 2) Don't compile C code with a C++ compiler. They are different languages! (just in case) 3) You have to pass **the address** of the buffer.

Comment: @Olaf 1) The question seems quite clear to me; 2) Who said anything about a C++ compiler? 3) Don't answer in comments.

Comment: "I've tried making buffer both a char and an int," only describe the code.  Better and clearer to post the code as it best conveys what you did.  Same for warnings.  Post the warning rather than describe it.  "warnings that it expects a void * argument" leaves open to interpretation what "it" is.

Comment: @ca: 1) The question lacks the declaration of the names. 2) Read carefully: "(just in case)" 3) See 1, this is not an answer! 4) I'm not a clairvoyant, YMMV

Answer (score 7):

You could use the function `int fgetc (FILE *fp)`.
The return value will be an `int` value from 0 to 255 or `EOF`.

Comment: Simplicity wins every time. One line of code, no buffers, no pointers, no arrays. This is by far the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Binary operation can be performed on `char` data type with `unsigned`. Even if its an array binary operation can be done to the single element of the array.

for your reference.

`ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);`

buffer has to be address of the `character` or `character array`, in your single `char` is sufficient. If you want to use array use the element `array[0]` and perform operation on that.

As mentioned in the comments above

```
unsigned char c; 
read(file, &c, 1);
```

Comment: Use `unsigned char` if you want to perform bitwise operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can read into a char array as you (supposedly) know how to do, and then perform your binary operations on the first element of that array.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t; /* Not necessary if you are using C99, i.e. <stdint.h>. */

uint8_t buffer[BUF_SIZE] = {0};
    .
    .
    .
if (fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer[0]), 1, file) == 1)
{
    buffer[0] ^= 0xFFu; /* Or any other bit-wise operation. */
}
```

Refer -
1. https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread
2. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer